# Именованные сущности

Tags: java, имена

Доброго времени суток! Передо мной была поставлена задача,которая звучит так:

> "Разработать прототип системы, определяющий в произвольном тексте на украинском языке именованные сущности: имена людей, фирм, даты и денежные единицы."

С датами и валютами проблем не было,а вот с именами и фирмами появились.Пытался решить задачу подобным образом,но не помогло:

```
public void checkFirms(){
    String firmp = "\"([А-Я][а-я]+\\s?)+\"|([А-Я][а-я]+\\s){2,5}";
    Pattern pf = Pattern.compile(firmp);
    Matcher mf = pf.matcher(input);
    while(mf.find()){                      //ФИРМЫ
        firm+=mf.group()+"\n"; 
    } 
}
public void CheckNames(){
    String namep = "[А-Я][а-я]+"; 
    Pattern pn = Pattern.compile(namep);
    Matcher mn = pn.matcher(input);
    while(mn.find()){                               //ИМЕНА
        String [] nameChecker= firm.split("/n");
        for( int i=0;i<nameChecker.length;i++){
            if(!nameChecker[i].contains(mn.group())){
               name+=mn.group()+"\n";
            }
            else{
            continue;
           }   
        }
}}
```

Выводит все ,что с большой большой буквы в имена,а в фирмы выводит только если словосочетание в кавычках.Может кто-то помочь?Пишу на Java

Comment: так а в чем конкретно у вас проблема?

Comment: Я тоже не совсем понял проблему... Каким образом вы решили искать имена и названия фирм? Первое, что мне приходит в голову - искать заглавные буквы кирилицы, а также кавычки. Можо получить массив чаров и бежать по нему. Каждый чар является цифрой. Заглавне буквы кирилицы будут идти подряд. Плюс кавычки. Таким образом, вам надо проверят, находится ли цифра очередного чара соотвествующему диапазону плюс номеру кавычек. А дальше дело техники.

Comment: Ну,проблема в том,что в выводе одно и то же словосочетание будет в двух разных текстовых полях . Т.е. ,например,словосочетение "Московский Мясокомбинат" будет добавлено в текстовое поле 1 "имя",как "Московский" и "Мясокомбинат",а в текстовое поле 2 как "Московский Мясокомбинат".А мне нужно,чтобы оно добавлялось только во второе поле

Comment: Простите, я редко пользуюсь регуляркой. Это может быть удобно, но в целом она довольно медленная. Как по мне - с чарами проще, быстрее и такие проблемы, как у вас, решаются в два счета

Comment: как-то очень уж в лоб вы всё ищете в своих примерах... я бы чуть больше серого вещества добавил в них: в частности, фирма скорее всего будет точно фирмой, если будет следовать за организационно-правовой формой с большой буквы и/или в кавычках, типа ООО "Роги та Копiта", или там ТОВ "Роги та Копiта". 
Имеет смысл добавлять все найденные названия в динамический словарь, что позволит в дальнейшем находить эти названия и без организационно-правовой формы - типа "Роги і копита заявили про любов до тварин".

Comment: С именами чуть сложнее - но можно попробовать искать сочетания из двух слов с большой буквы, проверить только чтобы они не были названиями фирм (по словарю) или абревиатурами. Также имеет смысл вести словарь имен и фамилий - эти словари вы в принципе можете взять готовые у филологов, а словари фирм можно тоже взять где-то, хотя они для каждого региона свои, но я не знаю какая задача - какие именно фирмы нада находить, не все же включая те что зарегистрированы на Мадагаскаре...